# Why can't I unlock a KeepassXC file located on a NTFS volume mounted in Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, ntfs, keepass

In Ubuntu 19.10, I can't unlock a password-protected KeepassXC file stored on a mounted NTFS volume, but if I copy it to an ext4 volume I can open it. I can read and write other file types to the NTFS volume (e.g., odt). The NTFS partition is mounted in fstab as `ntfs auto,user,rw 0 0`. What permissions/options need to be changed in order to unlock the password-protected KeepassXC file on NTFS from within Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To unlock a KeePassXC file stored on a mounted NTFS partition in Ubuntu:

1. Open Ubuntu Software app and find KeePassXC
2. Click on Permissions
3. Toggle "Read/write files on removable storage devices" to on

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clip where the setting in Ubuntu 22.04 actually is:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XthTdRro4KA